# Get the number of rows in cart in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, cart

I ***found places online*** that show *how to get the number of items in the cart but how can I get the number of rows*?

For example, if there are **two different items in the cart** there will be two rows, if there are **three different items in the cart** there will be three rows, but if three items in the cart but two are the same item then there will be only two rows and three items.

**I need to get the number of rows in the cart?**

Comment: "but if three items in the cart but two are the same...." 

this should not happen. Normal magento functionality would be to increase the quantity of the "same item" by the quantity of said same item being added to cart. If you do see seperated line items in cart for same item, then you have a module that has altered cote behaviour

Comment: Yeah I understand what you mean. I'm not having that issue. If they add two of the same items and one different item then you get two rows. Three different items and you get three rows. But I would like to get the number of rows.